# macOS Big Sur - set env vars for GUI apps?

Tags: big-sur, environment-variables, macos

I followed many methods on Ask Different as to how to change the `$PATH` environmental variable for GUI apps. Some of the methods may work for pre-Catalina macOS, some may work for Catalina, but none of them work for me on macOS Big Sur.

So here's the story - I installed `go` to `/usr/local/bin/go` with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh), and VS Code cannot find it -

[image]

Methods I've tried to solve this issue:

- `sudo launchctl config user path "/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`, and reboot.
- Edit `/etc/paths` so that it includes `/usr/local/bin`, and reboot.
- Other launchctl tricks.

So what's the recommended way to set env vars for GUI apps on macOS Big Sur? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you set the PATH (or at least the location of `go`)  within VS Code directly?

Comment: @nohillside Yes, I think I can set the path of the go binary in the go extension settings, but the same problem exists for R and other extensions in VS Code - there must be a better way to do it.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue trying to use SwiftBar. Running a python plugin, environment variables defined in bash/zsh/fish aren't available, and `launchctl setenv KEY value` doesn't work on Big Sur.

Answer (score 8):

The following worked for me to get an environment variable to be accessible from a GUI app (SwiftBar).

I created a plist file (eg; `com.example.set-env-vars.plist`) in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>setenv.MY_VARS</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>sh</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>launchctl setenv MY_VAR my_value</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then I rebooted for it to take effect. I suspect logging out and logging back in may be adequate, since stuff in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` should be applied at login.

If anyone can improve this answer, I'd love to know why this works but running `launchctl setenv MY_VAR my_value` from a terminal does not.

Swap out `MY_VAR` and `my_value` as needed. Note, I'm not sure whether this would allow you to do something like `launchctl setenv PATH "/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`, as I'm not sure whether `$PATH` would exist or expand properly.

Comment: For what it's worth, logging out wasn't enough for me, the variable only appeared after I actually rebooted.